# how to make ActionLink with 2 statements razor

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i want to make a ActionLink in my index page when 2 Statements are not in my "GraduationStatus" column. When the "GraduationStatus" is "Graduated" and "Pass" i want to have a link that redirect to the edit page of CohortSubscriptions Controller

```
<td>@{ 
       if (modelItem => item.GraduationStatus != "Graduated" && item.GraduationStatus != "Pass")
       {
           @Html.ActionLink(item.GraduationStatus, "Edit", new { id = item.GraduationStatus });
       }
     }
</td>



@foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrationId)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Registrations.FullName)
                            </td>
                            @*<td>@{ 
                                //var graduationStatus = db.CohortSubscriptions.Where(x => x.GraduationStatus != "GraduationStatus" && x.GraduationStatus != "Pass" );

                                if (modelItem => item.GraduationStatus != "Graduated" && item.GraduationStatus != "Pass")
                                {
                                    @Html.ActionLink(item.GraduationStatus, "Edit", new { id = item.GraduationStatus });
                                }
                                }
                            </td>*@
                            @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink(@Resource.Profile, "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                                    @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                                    {
                                        @Html.ActionLink(Resource.Edit, "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
                                    }
                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
```

This is the error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type "bool" because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: Can you post more of the razor page?  Why are you using a lambda in the `if` statement?  Why are you using `modelItem` and then `item.GraduationStatus`?

Comment: done @JosieG.Bigler

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if (modelItem => item.GraduationStatus != "Graduated" && item.GraduationStatus != "Pass")
```

to

```
if (item.GraduationStatus != "Graduated" && item.GraduationStatus != "Pass")
```

`@Html.DisplayFor()` requires a Function as it's first argument, so that's why you have that lambda expression there.  Doing `(modelItem => item.property)` is not typical for all Razorpage Html helpers.  In your `if` statement you just want those two properties and to return a boolean value (`true` or `false`).

Much like how later in the Razor view you have:

`@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))`, the same thing also applies to this block of code.